# Header row not appearing at the top of CSV while using Outputters

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

In u-sql query dumping data from one csv file to another through Outputterss.Csv() function but header row with column names is appearing at the end of file instead of top.Please find my code below.Thanks for the help.

```
@telDataResult=


SELECT 
"vin" AS vin,
"outsideTemperature" AS outsideTemperature,
"EventProcessedUtcTime" AS EventProcessedUtcTime,
"PartitionId" AS PartitionId,
"EventEnqueuedUtcTime" AS EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
"IoTHub" AS IoTHub

FROM @telData

UNION
SELECT 
t.vin ,
Convert.ToString(outsideTemperature) AS outsideTemperature 
EventProcessedUtcTime ,
PartitionId ,
EventEnqueuedUtcTime ,
IoTHub 
FROM 
@telData AS t 

UNION

SELECT 
t.vin ,
Convert.ToString(outsideTemperature) AS outsideTemperature 
EventProcessedUtcTime ,
PartitionId ,
EventEnqueuedUtcTime ,
IoTHub 

FROM 
@telData1 AS t;


OUTPUT @telDataResult
TO 
@"wasb://blobcontainer@blobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/cluster/logs/2016/outputofADLA.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a native outputter, the individual rows are written in a parallel fashion by multiple vertices, so there is no guarantee of order. We are currently working on supporting the output of header rows natively. In the meantime, you can use our custom outputter that writes header rows to output files. The custom outputter can be found in https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/HeaderOutputter. Using the HeaderOutputter, your code will look like the following.

```
@telDataResult= SELECT 
 t.vin ,
 Convert.ToString(outsideTemperature) AS outsideTemperature 
 EventProcessedUtcTime ,
 PartitionId ,
 EventEnqueuedUtcTime ,
 IoTHub 
 FROM 
      @telData;

OUTPUT @telDataResult TO <OutputFile>
USING new new HeaderOutputter.HeaderOutputter(quoting:false);
```

Comment: Some additional comments: The custom outputter **only** outputs the headers. You would have to add your own logic to add the other data. Also, please vote here for the feature to have the header rows written by the built-in outputter: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/10635558-generate-heading-rows-using-the-built-in-adla-outp.

Finally, you can add an order column to your rowset containing the header row and order on it in the `OUTPUT` statement to get the header row first. (note that the order column will be part of the output).

Comment: I have used what was finally suggest by Michael but i am getting error as :no entity of the required types has the specified name .

Comment: I see that it is now implemented. We have to just add a parameter to default outputters. `OUTPUT @data
TO "/output/docsamples/output_header.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader : true);`